# Something about the impedances of charge amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, audio, impedance, preamp

[image]

[image]

it is my understanding that due to the effect of virtual grounding, the input impedance of a charge amplifier is basically zero. If that's the case, then is there any reason to even worry about the differential or common mode impedance of the op amp I use? The LT1115 has a low differential input resistance of 15KOhm. Is there any reason one should care about this if the input impedance of the overall amplifier circuit is just considered to be 0 anyways?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried simulating your circuit to see how it behaves? Simulation is a big thing these days.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking these specs are indeed irrelevant.

BUT: You need very small input bias current, because this current will charge the feedback capacitance and affect the actual charge input measurement.

So you want FET input op-amps, which have input bias currents in the pA range or below. And it just so happens that FET op-amps *also* have large input impedance.

But if you find or design a FET op-amp with low input current, but atrociously low input impedance, it would be still well suited for your circuit.

Comment: Wouldn't low input current necessarily imply high input impedance?

Comment: @Hearth Hmm  IMO the two specs are separate. Imagine an \$I_b(V_{ICM})\$ line that is a small zigzag around 0. Its slope (input admittance) could be locally large, but the absolute value of the bias current could be small. I guess it will be hard to design such a thing, but I didn't want to claim that it's outright impossible. E.g. the \$I_b(V_{ICM})\$ line could have a small jump right at the working point of the amp which surely can happen. -> low current, but also low input impedance

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, simulation. To help the OP start, here is the effect of differential input resistance in a LT1115 circuit:

[image: diff-res]

Naive calculation with a time constant of this waveform, approx. 2.35us, gives LT1115's differential resistance estimate of 2.35us / 100pF = 23.5K, close enough to datasheet's 15K.

The effect of common mode input resistance in a LT1115 circuit:

[image: common-res-620MEG]

A time constant of this waveform is approx. 0.062s / 100pF = 620MEG, also not far from datasheet's 250MEG.

Is it enough to decide whether `one should care about` `a low differential input resistance of 15KOhm` or a common mode input resistance rulez?

The OP should worry first not about a leakage from virtual ground, which is defined by the device they use in CSA. The design workflow direction is quite opposite: they select or receive the design goals and choose the components they require to use.

Do they have to measure pressure of vibrations? If the quasistatic quantity is required, how would they reset a quiescent current? Et cetera

[image: reset]